# What does it mean for readers to have their own timeline

Tags: clojure

In his talk [are we there yet](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Are-We-There-Yet-Rich-Hickey), at 57:25, Rich Hickey talks about multiversion concurrency control. One of the advantages listed is the ability for readers to have their own timeline. I'm curious what this means in practice. Is this done by simply letting the reader save a history of observed values? Or is it somehow done with the help of of clojure's STM? It would be nice to see an example of how this is used in clojure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Rich meant that readers outside a transaction see the world as it is in it's current state every time they try to read a value and this world view is individual for each of them.

When you've got two uncorrelated functions (not bound in the same transaction) trying to get current value of a variable (atom, ref, agent, etc...), they are not guaranteed to obtain (see) the same value.

Example:

```
(let [
  ; 1.
  counter (ref 0)

  ; 2.
  _ (.start (Thread. (fn [] (while (< @counter 1000000) 
                               (dosync (alter counter inc))))))
  _ (Thread/sleep 10)

  ; 3.
  _ (let [r1 @counter
          _ (Thread/sleep 1)
          r2 @counter]
       (println "free reader 1: " r1 "free reader 2:" r2))
  ; 4.
  _ (dosync (let [r1 @counter
                  _ (Thread/sleep 1)
                  r2 @counter]
       (println "frozen reader 1: " r1 "frozen reader 2:" r2)))

  _ (println "---------------------------------")])
```

sample output:

```
free reader 1:  30573 free reader 2: 31295
snapshot reader 1:  105498 snapshot reader 2: 105498
---------------------------------
free reader 1:  37567 free reader 2: 38369
snapshot reader 1:  181392 snapshot reader 2: 181392
---------------------------------
free reader 1:  37317 free reader 2: 88570
frozen reader 1:  467471 frozen reader 2: 467471
---------------------------------
```

How it works:

1. Declare a counter variable as ref (transactional variable type) and set its initial value to 0
2. Create Java thread with anonymous function that changes the counter by incrementing it in a loop and ".start" the thread.
3. Read counter in a two step way, separated by 1 ms delay and print each value. As you can see both values are different as expected. This simulates separate time lines, when two objects observing the same object receive different data.
4. The same as above but in a world snapshot. Putting sleep function does not effect the output values. Both of them are equal.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I thought that own timeline meant that readers have access to a history of values, but I see now that it just means that they see the current state.